# Trim "Minify" inline css at runtime, expand it at edit time

Tags: php

My custom WP theme has a text block in the theme options panel that allows the user to create and maintain a custom css block that is applied to the site template at runtime.

I would like to trim or "minify" this content before its stored in the database, but retain all the whitespace when its presented back to the user for editing.

Would this be possible?

For example, if the user has entered the following as their custom css code...

```
.red {color:red;}

.green {color:green;}

.blue {color:blue;}
```

Then I would like to store it in the database as:

```
.red{color:red;}.green{color:green;}.blue{color:blue;}
```

But still display it as it was input (ie, retain all the white space and line breaks) when the user is editing the content via my theme options panel.

Comment: Hard drive space being about the cheapest thing available, is it that important to minify before storage at all?

Comment: It's really not about storage space, but rather about speed of delivery. Every little "bit" counts (literally :)

Comment: @Scott B - You will save at most 2KB from minifying. That data can be transferred *faster* than the time it takes to minify.

Comment: In the example you have, you're reducing size by about 10%.  Assuming that's somewhat representative, you might want to think if it's worth the maintenance trouble...10% reduction size isn't that big, and depending on how complex the solution for unminifying for display is, it may not be big.  (Without knowing your exact situation of course, I'm having a tough time picturing a solution that won't work well at speed X, but will at speed .9X)

Comment: @Nick, @Coronatus, @Beska - It would not be minified at runtime, rather, its minified once, then just extracted as is. The example is just for ease of explanation. Its a completely minimalist example. Real world edits would be much more verbose.

Comment: Daniel Vassallo has good suggestion so far.

Comment: No, I understood that it wouldn't be minified at runtime. You store it minified. But it's only 10% smaller (10% is just an example...the real average might be 5% or 15% or whatever). That means that the amount you're sending over the wire is only 10% smaller...and really, not even that, since for relatively small files like most css files, a lot of the time is taken up by connection, handshake, headers, etc. My gut (without testing obviously) tells me that this isn't going to be a big win. Still, if you have empirical evidence that shows that this is a win for you, go for it.

Comment: @ScottB - If you're delivering it gzipped (and you should be), removal of whitespace will make a **very** small difference in delivery payload.  Also, if storage space isn't an issue, store both, this ensures your user gets to edit the way they left it.

Answer (score 2):

If you strip the whitespace from your data before storing it, that whitespace information is lost. You may therefore want to consider the following options:

- Keep two columns in the database: Original CSS, and Minified CSS. Send the minified version to the browser, but the user would get the original version for editing in the back-end. If the user makes some changes, commit to both the original and minified fields.
- You can also simply store just the original version in the database without any whitespace stripping. Then simply pre-processes the CSS before sending it to the browser. However, hard disk space being very cheap, you can avoid the pre-processing step by using the technique suggested above.
- Store the minified version, as you suggested in the question, then apply some formatting logic at the back-end, such that a line break would be added after each semicolon, etc. Obviously the user might have used a different code formatting that the one generated. You can also apply the formatting Logic on the client-side instead, using JavaScript.

Comment: Another solution might be to do everything with minified css on the server, and use JavaScript on the client side to unminify before display...probably pretty straightforward to write as a regex...and the processing is passed to the client so there's no additional server load.

Comment: Daniel, good points. One option that might help would be to store the content in a css file (that's used at runtime) and also store it in the db. Use the db copy (unminified) for editing, but sync to the file (minified) upon save. I like the file approach due to css caching that's not possible with inline styles. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Scott B: If you are ok with storing the user-generated CSS on the filesystem, that is another valid option. However note that you can still link to an external CSS sheet, by generated one with php at runtime. This script could gather the style data from the database, and then output it using the `text/css` mime-type.

Answer (score 1):

Google has created a PHP class to help developers minify CSS located on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a zipping algorithm, not a replace space. Look for the zipping algos and use them to compress your css when sending over and unzip at the client-side. I think html provides some options. Will check and add comments.

Comment: look at these -
   * http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html
   * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555/best-way-to-compress-html-css-js-with-mod-deflate-and-mod-gzip-disabled

Comment: also can have a look at http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php

Comment: Now here's an interesting option.  Might get some relatively big results from this, since large css files probably compress quite well indeed.

Comment: Thanks pinaki, I will check the resources.